# Git merge subtrees of two local branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, subtree

For the life of me I can't get `git subtree merge` to work. Here's my situation:

I'm working on a built-in part of [Moodle](http://moodle.org) called Workshop. The code lives at `mod/workshop` in the `moodle` directory. I have to upgrade my local Moodle to 2.5 and get my Workshop changes to work in it. So, the obvious solution to me is:

1. Checkout the `MOODLE_25_STABLE` branch from the upstream
2. Create a branch called `MOODLE_25_STABLE_workshop` based on that branch
3. Merge `mod/workshop` from my `MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop` branch into `MOODLE_25_STABLE_workshop`

That would be *easy* if I wanted to merge every single file from `MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop` into `MOODLE_25_STABLE_workshop` but I'm only interested in replaying my commits to the `mod/workshop` directory. Is there an easier way than to `cherry-pick` my way through six months of commits? Because I really, really don't want to do that.

Things I have already tried:

```
$ git subtree merge --prefix=mod/workshop/ MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop:mod/workshop
error: 402c67f6fedc96a6fed76e663df4e5af9dfa094e: expected commit type, but the object dereferences to tree type
```

and

```
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop
$ git read-tree --prefix=mod/workshop/ -u MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop:mod/workshop
error: Entry 'mod/workshop/aggregate.php' overlaps with 'mod/workshop/aggregate.php'.  Cannot bind.
$ gormster:Documents/moodle$ git read-tree -m --prefix=mod/workshop/ -u MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop:mod/workshop
fatal: Which one? -m, --reset, or --prefix?
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There is no `git subtree` command. Please, make sure you copy & paste exact commands.

Comment: Yes there is, at least there is in my version. I copy and pasted the exact commands. http://imgur.com/iPUDv3z

Comment: Great. There indeed is such command, but it is undocumented. The [official documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs) has no clue about it nor has the one installed locally though the command exists.

Comment: I'd try `git subtree merge --prefix=mod/workshop/ MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop` without the other path. But it's just a guess and it is quite likely it won't work anyway. The subtree merge is for when one branch only contains subtree, not when both branches contain everything, but you only want to merge changes to some part.

Comment: Right. It looks like in my situation I actually should be using a rebase anyway, but that has its own problems, which I'll be posting a question about in a minute :P

Comment: No, rebase won't help you, because rebase just merges each revision independently and forgets the old history. But the merge strategy is still the same.

Comment: Yeah - it was actually a weird thing where I had a (squashed) rebase in my commit history that was causing it to try to change a whole bunch of stuff. Once I removed that commit, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a merge (sans the recursive part of the strategy for dealing with criss-cross merge) is just patching the local tree with diff from most recent common ancestor to the remote one.

There is a command to get the merge base, `git merge-base`, but `git diff` is even able to call it on it's own if you use the `...` (3 instead of 2 dots) operator.

So the merge is:

```
git diff HEAD...MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop -- mod/workshop/ | git apply -3
```

and than you commit it.

You probably shouldn't try recording `MOODLE_23_STABLE_workshop` as base, because it really isn't. If you did, next merge would assume you merged all changes and explicitly reverted the ones outside `mod/workshop/`. On the other hand if you don't record the parent, next merge will try to re-apply the changes, causing unnecessary conflicts if the same areas are modified again as git is smart enough to recognize already applied diff, but can't tell when the diff obsoletes other changes.

Comment: Okay, that really really sounds like the solution, except git apply doesn't seem to want to give me control of conflict resolution...

Comment: Which is fixed with -3! Marked as solution. Thank you sir/madam.

Comment: Editing the answer to include the -3 option. It often helps and should never hurt.